# Wifi problems ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-gnome, 17.04, iwlwifi

If I reinstall ubuntu 16.10 as provided by my hardware supplier the wifi works. If I upgrade the distro to 17.04 wifi has problems. Is this a known problem?

I also see lots of log errors for wifi:

https://pastebin.com/3mjKpMFP